# AWS Cloud 9 clear cache and used Memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide

I am using free tier AWS cloud 9 environment. After using it for a while it started showing that Memory is almost full. But I see cache has taken most of the memories. Do someone knows how to clear cache and free up some space? Or should I upgrade to paid version? I am attaching my memory usage.
[image]

Comment: You have to threat it like an Linux machine. Maybe this article could help you further: https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```